# Is it possible to add Queue Data to DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, datatable, queue

I am adding Items in **Queue"<"string">"** Asynchronously to Queue.Instead of *Inserting row by row* for each data of Queue using INSERT query, I want to add these items to DataTableOnly when **if(evtLogQueue.Count==1000)**. So that the DataTable could be used further for Bulk Insert using **BulkCopy** to SQLServerDB.

I would like to know is it Possible to do? if YES then how? or any other suggestion?

Sample Code:

```
static Queue<string> evtLogQueue = new Queue<string>();

public static void AddItemsToQueue(string itm)
        {

            evtLogQueue.Enqueue(itm);
            Console.WriteLine("Length of Queue:" + evtLogQueue.Count);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you can do this by adding some code to your `AddItemsToQueue(string itm)` method.

```
public static void AddItemsToQueue(string itm)
    {
        evtLogQueue.Enqueue(itm);
        // Add the following code
        if (evtLogQueue.Count == 1000)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Log");
            foreach (var log in evtLogQueue)
            { 
                DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                dr["Log"] = log;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            evtLogQueue.Clear();     // Most probably you will also need to clear the queue.
            SendBulkData(dataTable); // Send the bulk data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Asif!
Now i want to set a Time Intervcal or to Schedule the QUEUE to Insert all Data to DataBase on specific time Interval say AFTER EACH 30 MINUTES any suggestion?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE, I think you don't need to schedule the queue to insert the data into database, if you want to do this for just avoid locking ... The more appropriate and straight forward approach will be to send data after every 1000 logs to database asynchronously using Thread or Task.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

Inside AddItemsToQueue(string itm) check for the number of elements in the queue.

Once you get the number is 1000, run a for loop and insert data to the data table.

Please check the below mentioned link for doing bulk copy

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Thank for Reply! i will try! Now i want to set a Time Intervcal or to Schedule the QUEUE to Insert all Data to DataBase on specific time Interval say after each 30mins how to do any sample code?